# how to find a specific word having random located newline

Tags: regex

As I stated on the title.
I'm try to find regex result on a specific word(like apple) having random newline(\r\n) special character.

Illustrate more detail...

Let's find a word 'apple' on the text file. but We don't know where is exact position of newline(\r\n) on the file like below...

---

```
                                                                           ap
ple
```

**or**

```
                                                                         appl
e
```

---

I also googled many pages but I couldn't find the answer.

Should I have to write beginner regex like below?

(a\r\npple|ap\r\nple|app\r\nle|appl\r\ne|apple\r\n|)

I need to find more smarter regex to find exact word.

---

**updated.**

the word can be vary like "ripe apple", "rotten apple" and "brightapple".
In the case of third item, white space removed by writer.

updated

i have many txt files. i have to find the string within those.
So remove /r/n is not useful and cannot handle(too much menory and time required).

Comment: Yes, you need to insert the pattern that may occur in between the letters. Maybe `a\s*p\s*p\s*l\s*e`

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you mean you want to ignore all whitespace and capture the word? If not, how do you decide which lines are part of a previous word, and which are a new word entirely? See http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html for a brilliant and thorough treatment of regexes. Otherwise please include a code example so we can see the target capture.

Comment: Wiktor Stribizew - surely a\s*?p\s*?p\s*?l\s*?e would be an improvement on that dreadful regex...

Comment: @Hektor Why? What's the point of making the quantifiers non-greedy?

Comment: thanks for everyone.
I'm not make a program. just use a regex. and I also care about white space between character. I still find a possible ways..

Comment: @melpomene In case the word appears more than once in the text?

Comment: @Hektor That makes no sense. Greediness doesn't affect whether a regex matches or where it matches.

Comment: @Hektor With `a\s*?p` the `?` really does not change anything. Since `p` is not in `\s`, there is no ambiguity that `?` would resolve. other than e.g. with `a.*?p`.

Comment: @melpomene Surely a greedy regex will match the longest possible string, even encompassing numerous instances of the match within that string if necessary?

Comment: Actually my mistake, in this context it would make no difference...whatsoever!

Comment: I'd recommend simply stripping all [\r\n] and then look for the word.  Clean your data up (with a regex) and then search for your term (with another regex)

Comment: sniperd , my fault... your comment is true, but I have thousand of text files which have to find words. It's not a case your mentioned. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to take the naive approach ("beginner regex") if you want to use regular expressions, since they belong to the type 3 grammars and cannot express the state needed (see also [The difference between Chomsky type 3 and Chomsky type 2 grammar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11549271/the-difference-between-chomsky-type-3-and-chomsky-type-2-grammar))